# Proving or disproving that $\{(x,y) : xy > 0\}$ is open

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here's what I have so far:

Let $D = \{(x, y):xy>0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $(a,b) \in D$ such that, WLOG, $a\leq b$. Let $\delta = |a|$.

$$
(a,b)\in D \Rightarrow ab > 0  \Rightarrow (a > 0 \wedge b>0) \vee (a < 0 \wedge b < 0) \Rightarrow \delta > 0.
$$

Consider the set $P = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |(x, y) - (a, b) < \delta\}$. Let $(m, n) \in P$ be arbitrary and fixed.

$$
(m, n) \in P \Rightarrow |(m, n) - (a, b)| < \delta = |a| \\ \Rightarrow m^2 - 2am +a^2 +n^2 -2nb +b^2 < a^2 \\ \Rightarrow m^2 -2am + +n^2 - 2nb +b^2 < 0
$$

Case 1: $m = 0$
$$
m = 0 \Rightarrow n^2 -2nb + b^2 = (n-b)^2 < 0
$$
This is cannot occur, because any real number squared is positive.

Case 2: $n = 0$
$$
n = 0 \Rightarrow (m-a)^2 + b^2 < a^2 \\ b \geq a \Rightarrow b^2 \geq a^2 \Rightarrow (m-a)^2 \leq 0 \Rightarrow m = a \\ m = a \Rightarrow |(m, n) - (a, b)| = |(a, 0) - (a, b)| = |(0, -b)| = |b| > |a|
$$

This is a contradiction. $(m,n) \in P \Rightarrow |(m, n) - (a, b)| < \delta = |a|$, but $m = 0 \Rightarrow |(m, n) - (a, b)| > |a|$

I've tried proving $m > 0 \Rightarrow n > 0$ and $m < 0 \Rightarrow n < 0$, but I can't seem to do it; it almost seems like I'll need to break it down into more cases. If I do have to break it down into even more cases, I'd much rather toss this and look for a simpler, more elegant proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

**Sketch of proof.** The function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, with $$f(x,y)=xy,$$ is continuous, and hence $f^{-1}[A]\subset\mathbb R^2$ is open whenever $A\subset\mathbb R$ is open.

The set in question is $f^{-1}\big[(0,\infty)\big]$, and hence it is indeed open.

Comment: Is this *not* the proof...?

Comment: Yes, I believe that my answer provides the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that $\{(x,y)\;|\;xy\leq 0\}$ is closed. Take a sequence $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in the set that converges to $(x,y)$. Then $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$. Since sequenc is in the set we have that $x_ny_n\leq 0$. Since inequalities preserve limits we have that $xy\leq 0$ implying that the set is closed.