# Set of xy > 0 in the plane

Tags: calculus, general-topology

$$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} \mid xy>0 \}$$
A is open. It's boundary are the axis. A = A' .but, why is not closed, and A≠ to his closure?

Comment: $A$ doesn't contain $(0,0)$  but its closure does.

Comment: Also Its closure doesn't contain the axis?

Comment: What do you mean by $A=A'$?

Comment: The closure of $A$ contains the axes. $A$ does not contain any point on the axes. So the closure is strictly bigger. Not sure what $A=A'$ means.

Comment: A' : all the limit points of A. A is not closed because its complement is closed?

Comment: Open/closed confuses me, because R is open and closed, so, can't be logically opposite, i guess...?

Comment: [0,1) is not open.  If open and closed were logical opposites,   then [0,1) would be closed, which it isn't.

Comment: So, why do you think $A=A'$? Every point on the axes is in $A'$, but no point on the axes is in $A$.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks Gerry. (0,2) is a limit point of A, but $\notin A$, isn't it?

Comment: The complement of A, is not open and not closed, I'm right? Sorry for so many questions

Comment: In topology, “open” and “closed” are NOT antonyms. A subset of a topological space is closed if its complement is open.

Comment: One more. Is $A \cup \partialA$ simply connected?

Comment: As $A$ is open, its complement is closed. If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question, not as a comment on this question.

Comment: See also: [Proving or disproving that $\{(x,y) : xy > 0\}$ is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/645245)