# Proving that set is closed

Tags: general-topology

I need to check whether set $A=\left\{(x,y)|xy\ge0\right\}$ is open or closed. I proved that it is not open. When I want to check whether it is closed, it comes down to prove that $A^C=\left\{(x,y)|x<0\lor y<0\right\}\cap\left\{(x,y)|x>0 \lor y>0\right\}$ is open, where $A^C$ is complement of $A$. So if I take point $(-1,0)$ it is easy to prove that $A^C$ is not open, so it is not closed as well. Is this correct?
Initial set $A$ I wrote like $A=\left\{(x,y)|x\ge0\land y\ge0\right\}\cup\left\{(x,y)|x\le0\land y\le0\right\}$, and that is how I got $A^C$.

Comment: I don’t think (-1,0) is in $A^c$. $-1 \times 0 = 0$, so the point satisfy $xy \geq 0$.

Comment: Here is a similar older question: [Proving or disproving that $\{(x,y) : xy > 0\}$ is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/645245).

Comment: If you already know something about continuous maps, you have that $f(xy)=xy$ is continuous and you're looking here at the points such that $f(xy)\ge0$.
If you already know about relation between convergence and closed set, you can check whether for sequences such that $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$ you get from $x_ny_n\ge0$ (for each $n$) that also $xy\ge0$.

Comment: It might help you to draw the picture to see what set you're actually dealing with. (But the decomposition you wrote gives a good idea: $A=\left\{(x,y)|x\ge0\land y\ge0\right\}\cup\left\{(x,y)|x\le0\land y\le0\right\}$. You could also try to show that both these sets are closed.)

Comment: Right, i think i made a mistake with $A^C$ it should be $\left\{(x,y)|x<0 \land y>0\right\}$, which is obviously open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are considering the points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ then $A^C=\left\{(x,y)|x<0\land y>0\right\}\cup\left\{(x,y)|x>0 \land y<0\right\}$.

For any $(x,y)\in\ A^C$ let $d_1=\text{distance of $(x,y)$ to the axis $Ox$}$ and $d_2=\text{distance of $(x,y)$ to the axis $Oy$}$.

Then for $d=\frac{\text{min}\{d_1,d_2\}}{2}$ the disk of center $(x,y)$ and radius $d$ is contained in $A^C$.

Comment: In $A^C$ you mean $\land$ instead of $\lor$, because complement is $\left\{(x,y)|xy<0\right\}$?

Comment: Yes, I do. I will edit. Thanks